# Can “but that” stand in for “except when/for”?

Tags: grammaticality

Consider “I did not scold him but that he deserved it.” To me, this is correct, though archaic.

In general, can “but that” stand in for “except for (when),” “if not for the fact that,” and similar?

If correct, how archaic is this usage, exactly? I’m not sure how to search for this uniquely in Google Ngrams because “but that” can be used in other ways.

Comment: It's very archaic, and I wouldn't use it unless I was writing a medieval fantasy.

Comment: "Butt that" is an expression you'd use in a story about goats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, *but* is used with the meaning:

> *except for the fact* [or *were it not for the fact that*]
>
> - would have protested but that he was afraid ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/but))

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/but-that) defines the phrase ***but that*** as meaning:

> that there is not some chance that.

However, this is not often met even in written texts nowadays, so unless you master it well and have the right context for it, better stick to the more common ways of expressing this.

*[The Oxford Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Oxford_Dictionary_of_English/anecAQAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22she%20would%20have%20screamed,%20but%20that%20her%20cry%20would%20have%20called%20her%20masters%22&pg=PA237&printsec=frontcover)* clearly lists it as archaic:

> ***but that*** *archaic* 
> other than that; except that:
>
> - She would have screamed, ***but that*** her cry would have called her masters.

There is no statement of a clear date when this expression began to be used. [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/but)'s explanations are pretty scarce too:

> Not used as a conjunction until late Old English. As an introductory expression, early 13c.